# Safe fluent cast in Kotlin?

Tags: generics, kotlin, casting, fluent

Having these extension functions:

```
inline fun <reified OUT> Any.cast(): OUT = this as OUT
inline fun <reified IN, reified OUT: IN> IN.downcast(): OUT = this as OUT
inline fun <reified IN: OUT, reified OUT> IN.upcast(): OUT = this as OUT
```

I can use them this way:

```
val x1: Number = 42
val x2: String = "abc"
val x3: Double = 3.14

val y1: Int = x1.downcast<Number, Int>()
val y2: CharSequence = x2.upcast<String, CharSequence>()
val y3: Float = x3.cast<Float>() // dangerous, crash
```

The **first** problem is I have to write:

```
x1.downcast<Number, Int>()
```

Instead of

```
x1.downcast<Int>()
```

The **second** problem is that even if I achieved `x1.upcast<Int>()` syntax, `IN` generic parameter could easily be deduced as `Any`, so it will always work, which is not desired.

---

Example below shows simplified bad case of real life scenario:

```
interface A1Able
class B1Impl : A1Able { val desiredField = 42 }
class C1Impl : A1Able

interface A2Able
class B2Impl : A2Able { val someField: A1Able = C1Impl() }
class C2Impl : A2Able { val someField: A1Able = B1Impl() }

interface A3Able
class B3Impl : A3Able { val someField: A2Able = C2Impl() }
class C3Impl : A3Able { val someField: A2Able = B2Impl() }

interface A4Able
class C4Impl : A4Able { val someField: A3Able = B3Impl() }

fun main() {
  val source: A4Able = C4Impl()
  val desiredField = ((((source as C4Impl).someField as B3Impl).someField as C2Impl).someField as B1Impl).desiredField
}
```

And that's what I call **parenthesis hell**. With Syntax I try to achieve this looks as below (unsafe cast version):

```
source.cast<C4Impl>().someField.cast<B3Impl>().someField.cast<C2Impl>().someField.cast<B1Impl>().desiredField
```

Althrough it's not a shorter syntax, it's much more readable and there is no **parenthesis hell**. The problem is that I lose type checking this way, so I could possibly write `"abc".cast<Int>()` and cause exception.

---

**How can I make this safer, and keep the fluent syntax?**

Comment: You have the terms upcast and downcast reversed. Downcasting (casting to a subclass) is inherently unsafe. Using a generic method would keep you from accidentally casting to something that couldn't possibly be a subclass, but since you have to check eligibility anyway to be safe, I don't see how using a generic method is worthwhile. Upcasting (casting to a superclass) is redundant, so you shouldn't need a function for it.

Comment: @Tenfour04. Yeah, I messed up up and down :D I added upcasting only for completeness.